# Test не пройден JUnit

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

В одном пакете есть 2 класса, один из них тестовый

```
package main;
public class Amount{
    public int sum(int v1, int v2){
        System.out.println("Adding values " + v1 + " + " + v2);
        return v1 + v2;
    }
}

package main;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
public class AmountTest{
    Amount project = new Amount();
    int sum = project.sum(2,5);
    int resSum = 7;
    @Test
    public void testSum(){
        System.out.println("@TestSum(): " + sum + " = " + resSum);
        assertEquals(sum, resSum);
    }
}
```

Но проверка заканчивается неудачно

```
junit:
    [junit] Running main.AmountTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.017 sec
    [junit] Test main.AmountTest FAILED
```

Почему?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

```
<path id="classpath" location="lib/*.jar">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
<path id="application" location="build/jar/Project.jar" />

<target name="junit">
        <junit printsummary="yes">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath" />
                <path refid="application" />
            </classpath>
            <batchtest fork="yes">
                <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*Test.java"/>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

Comment: Запустил ваш код - тест успешно пройден. В действительности все так, как вы описали?

Comment: @Etki не вводите в заблуждение автора вопроса. С точки зрения Java это код корректен.

Comment: Дело не в том что тест неверен, иначе бы у вас было сообщение типа `Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`, в вашем же случае произошла ошибка, не связанная с ожидаемыми условиями теста, потому у вас `Errors: 1`.

Comment: Может, в Ant проблема. поскольку я работаю не в IDE. Я добавил junit библиотеку в папку lib корня проекта, где должны быть все внешние библиотеки. Добавляю код Ant.

Comment: @a_gura, я и сказал, что у меня подозрения, не более.

Answer (score 2):

В Junit (и скорее всего, и в других тестовых фреймворках) есть два стандартных метода:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //Код, выполняемый перед запуском ВСЕХ тестов
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
//Код, выполняемый после запуска ВСЕХ тестов 
}
```

Т.е. ваш блок кода по созданию объекта и инициализации переменных можно перенести в метод setUp.

Но я бы сделал так:

```
public class AmountTest{

    private Amount project;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //Код, общий для всех тестов
        project = new Amount();       
    }

    @Test
    public void testSum(){
        //Локальные данные, которые нужны только в этом тесте
        int sum = project.sum(2,5);
        int resSum = 7;    
        System.out.println("@TestSum(): " + sum + " = " + resSum);
        assertEquals(sum, resSum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[[@romashechka](/users/17582/romashechka)](/users/17582/romashechka)

1. Для таких случаев существуют отчеты тестов. Я до сих пор с ними толком не ознакомился, но, в принципе, весь условный дебаг должен запихиваться именно туда. Насколько помню, практически дефолтный surefire имеет какую-то апишку для пробрасывания данных.
2. Вся инициализация, все данные должны лежать *внутри* теста. Я не могу сказать, корректно ли ява обрабатывает подобный код, но абсолютно точно могу сказать, что *снаружи* эта инициализация не должна валяться (data-provider'ы parametrized-тестов не в счет).